# How to find which IP addresses are connected to an access point?

Tags: wireless-access-point

Is their a way to find out what IP addresses or full resolved computer names are connected to a specific Access Point on a network?

Edit:
The APs are generic netgear routers running in AP mode with stock firmware.

Comment: What's the access point in question here? And are you using the stock firmware for it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are connected to the network:
Try Advanced IP Scanner. (Only used it once, long ago, use at own risk).

If you are not connected to the network:
I must say, I don't know how to get an IP from a mac address if you are not connected to the same network, but you can find the mac addresses of devices connected to a wireless access point by using airodump-ng from linux.

Below is an example airodump-ng output adapted from http://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=airodump-ng

CH  9 ][ Elapsed: 1 min ][ 2007-04-26 17:41 ][ WPA handshake: 00:14:6C:7E:40:80

BSSID              PWR RXQ  Beacons    #Data, #/s  CH  MB   ENC  CIPHER AUTH ESSID

00:09:5B:1C:AA:1D   11  16       10        0    0  11  54.  OPN              NETGEAR
 00:14:6C:7A:41:81   34 100       57       14    1   9  11e  WEP  WEP         bigbear 
 00:14:6C:7E:40:80   32 100      752       73    2   9  54   WPA  TKIP   PSK  teddy

BSSID              STATION            PWR   Rate   Lost  Packets  Probes

00:14:6C:7A:41:81  00:0F:B5:32:31:31   51   36-24    2       14
 (not associated)   00:14:A4:3F:8D:13   19    0-0     0        4    mossy 
 00:14:6C:7A:41:81  00:0C:41:52:D1:D1   -1   36-36    0        5
 00:14:6C:7E:40:80  00:0F:B5:FD:FB:C2   35   54-54    0       99    teddy

The top part shows all Access Points. Bottom part 2nd column shows devices connected to Bottom part 1st column Access Point. You can see two devices connected to 00:14:6C:7A:41:81 (bigbear).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Remember to comment

Answer (score 0):

1. What make / type AP are you referring too?
2. It is possible, on either the terminal or the GUI interface (normally the default gateway address in your browser) navigate to the dhcp server. You will be able to see the IP, hostname, MAC and time before the lease is going to be renewed. Ideally the ARP protocol would answer you question, as in Cisco we find it extremely useful to view connected devices. I know in Windows command prompt I've used the arp -a command to trace devices on the network route.

Comment: arp -a or the GUI would give me devices connected to the network, not just to the AP, right?

Comment: Yes, it would provide the devices' names connected to the network. If you are not too computer literate, I would suggest trying the GUI, which would be the default gateway address entered into your browser.

Comment: mmm, I need the device list connected only to the AP and not the network. Thge GUI on the router/gateway will show me everything connected to it. It doesn't show if the devices are connected through a particular AP.